# Update field with max and min value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to update a percentage field with a maximum value of `1` and a minimum of `0` with a relative value (eg. "add 25% to the current value")

This obviously doesn't work:

```
UPDATE table SET field = MAX(0, MIN(1, field+0.25))
```

**Update:**

If the value is eg `0.85` it should update to `1`

**Update**

I'm using this now:

```
UPDATE table SET field = GREATEST(0, LEAST(1, field+0.25))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET field = case when field > 0.75 
                 then 1
                 else field + 0.25
            end
```

Especially in MySQL you can do

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET field = least(1, field + 0.25)
```

For values that can also be negativ you can use

```
update your_table
SET field = case when field + ? > 1.0 then 1 
                 when field + ? < 0.0 then 0 
                 else field + ? 
            end
```

Comment: I've updated my questions since it doesn't work if the field is `0.85`

Comment: sorry: `0.6 => 0.85`, `0.75 => 1`, `0.85 => 1`, `1 => 1` Hope that makes sense

Comment: and with the `0` field should i do the same or is an `unsigned` field enough?

Comment: Updated an unsigned under the range would lead to an error and stop the  update. You can use `set field = greatest(0, field - 0.25)` if you can change the query.

Comment: Or you could do `SET field = case when field + 0.25 > 1.0 then 1 when field + 0.25 < 0.0 then 0
                     else field + 0.25 end` I assume the `+` and `-` is part of your variable you input in the query.